# Using Qmake in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, qt4, qmake

Normally, what I would do is to create two makefiles; one manually and another automatically using qmake. Right now, I'd like to find a way to use qmake inside the makefile that I've created manually.

Here it is:

#

```
# Copyright (C) 2011 OpenWrt.org
#
# This is free software, licensed under the GNU General Public License v2.
# See /LICENSE for more information.
#

include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk


PKG_NAME:=cloud
PKG_RELEASE:=1

PKG_BUILD_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_NAME)

include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk

define Package/cloud
  SECTION:=Cloud 
  CATEGORY:=cloud
  TITLE:=Package
endef

define Package/cloud/description
 Cloud Package
endef

define Build/Prepare
    mkdir -p $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
    $(CP) ./src/* $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/



endef

define Build/Configure
endef

define Build/Compile
    $(MAKE) -C $(PKG_BUILD_DIR) \
        CC="$(TARGET_CC)" \
        CFLAGS="$(TARGET_CFLAGS) -Wall" \
        LDFLAGS="$(TARGET_LDFLAGS)"
endef

define Package/cloud/install
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/usr/sbin
    $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/cloud$(1)/usr/sbin/

endef
$(eval $(call BuildPackage,cloud))
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You can call `qmake` just like you call `mkdir`